# Flushing successful mock POST request using Jasmine does not execute the AngularJS success function

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my AngularJS `post.js`:

```
angular.module("PostPageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        self.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.post(self.post, function() {
                self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };
    }]);
```

This is `base.js`:

```
angular.module("BaseApp", [])
    .config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfCookieName = 'csrftoken';
        $httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-CSRFToken';
    }])

    .config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])

    .factory("BaseService", ["$http", "$window", function($http, $window) {
        var self = this;
        self.posts = [];
        self.cerrorMessages = [];

        /* This function sets self.cerrorMessages. After calling this function,
         * you should do a callback to a function on the front-end which
         * sets cerrorMessage. */
        self.accessErrors = function(data) {
             self.cerrorMessages = [];
             for (prop in data) {
                 if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
                     /* if (data[prop] != null && data[prop].constructor ==  Object) {
                         self.accessErrors(data[prop]);
                     }
                     else { */
                     self.cerrorMessages.push(data[prop]);
                     // }
                 }
             }
         };

        self.add = {
            post: function(post, callback) {
                $http.post("/posts/", post)
                .then(function(response) {
                    $window.location.href = "/";
                }, function(response) {
                    self.accessErrors(response.data);
                    callback();
                });
            }
         };

        return self;
    }]);
```

And this is my `test_post.js`:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    beforeEach(module('PostPageApp'));

    var ctrl, $loc;

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $location, $httpBackend, BaseService) {
        ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl');
        $loc = $location;
        mockBackend = $httpBackend;

        spyOn(BaseService, 'add').and.callThrough();
        baseService = BaseService;
    }));

    it('should have an add function', function() {
        expect(ctrl.add).toBeDefined();
    });

    it('should be able to create a post object', function() {
        $loc.path('/post');
        ctrl.post = {'post':'Test post'}
        mockBackend.expectPOST('/posts/', ctrl.post)
            .respond(201, {'post':'TestPost', 'posting': 1});

        ctrl.add();

        mockBackend.flush();
        expect(baseService.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect($loc.path()).toEqual('/');
        expect(ctrl.cerrorMessages).toBeUndefined();
    });
});
```

Now, when I run `karma start`, it returns this:

```
Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) Controller: MainCtrl should be able to create a valid post object FAILED
    Expected spy add to have been called.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/u/Documents/CMS/CMSApp/static/js/karma/tests/test_post.js:32:33)
    Expected '/post' to equal '/'.
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/u/Documents/CMS/CMSApp/static/js/karma/tests/test_post.js:33:29)
Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.119 secChromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.163 secs / 0.119 secs)
```

As you can see, spy add was expected to be called, but since `Expected spy add to have been called.` was printed on the terminal, from my understanding, this means that it was not called, right?

Also, it also printed `Expected '/post' to equal '/'.` onto the terminal so this also means that the URL is still at `'/post'`, correct?

Any idea why the URL did not change and spy add was not called?

Comment: Where is `baseService` defined? You seem to be missing a `var` declaration

Comment: Also, you're testing too much here. If you're testing the controller, you should mock `BaseService`

Comment: @Phil `baseService = BaseService` (see the `beforeEach()` function in `test_post.js` and `BaseService` is the factory which is defined in `base.js`.

Comment: @Phil Hm okay, interesting. Basically, I wanted to check if the `add` function in my controller actually calls the `add.post` function in `BaseService / base.js` so I figured that I shouldn't create a mock `BaseService` (because I wanted to see if the actual `BaseService` is being called). Is that a valid reason to not create a mock `BaseService`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're testing the controller, **only** test the controller. That's why it's called a *unit test*. You should be mocking any external services.

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl, mockBaseService;

    beforeEach(function() {
        mockBaseService = {
            cerrorMessages: 'whatever',
            add: jasmine.createSpyObj('BaseService.add', ['post'])
        };

        mockBaseService.add.post.and.callFake(function(something, cb) {
            cb(); // execute the callback immediately
        });

        module('PostPageApp');

        inject(function($controller) {
            ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
                BaseService: mockBaseService
            });
        });
    });

    it('add calls through to BaseService.add.post', function() {
        ctrl.post = 'something'; // just adding this because I can't see it anywhere else

        ctrl.add();

        expect(mockBaseService.add.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl.post, jasmine.any(Function));
        expect(ctrl.cerrorMessages).toBe(mockBaseService.cerrorMessages);
    });
});
```

Comment: Okay thanks. Quick question: What does the line `add: jasmine.createSpyObj('BaseService.add', ['post'])` do? In the documentation here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Spies:_<code>createSpyObj</code>, they use a variable called `tape` and then do `tape.play` and `tape.pause`. In the code above, you do `add: jasmine.createSpyObj('BaseService.add', ['post'])` and then call ` mockBaseService.add.post.and.callFake(function(something, cb) {`. Shouldn't you do this instead: `add: jasmine.createSpyObj('add', ['post'])` in order to call `mockBaseService.add.post`?

Comment: @user2719875 It's just a name for the spy. I didn't think `add` was very descriptive whereas `BaseService.add` let's you know exactly what it represents. The name gets used in reporting, say if an expectation fails.

Comment: @user2719875 the `.and.callFake` part just tells the spy method what to do when it is called

Comment: Okay got it, thanks. Lastly, with regards to this line: `expect(mockBaseService.add.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl.post, jasmine.any(Function));` .. Shouldn't it instead be `expect(mockBaseService.add.post).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl.add);` because it was `ctrl.add` which called `mockBaseService.add.post`? How come you placed `ctrl.post` (which is a string.. how exactly does a string call a function?) and `jasmine.any(Function)` (instead of any function, shouldn't we be specific and verify that it was `ctrl.add` which called `mockBaseService.add.post`?) as the arguments?

Comment: @user2719875 no. The controller code in your question clearly shows `BaseService.add.post` being called with `self.post` (where `self` is the controller) and a function. The `toHaveBeenCalledWith` relates to the spy itself, not the function that called it. It's not `toHaveBeenCalledBy`