# Jasmine controller and mock service not being injected into the unit tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

This is my test_sp.js file:

```
describe('Controller: MainCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl, mockBaseService;

    beforeEach(function() {

        mockBaseService = {
            cerrorMessages: 'whatever',
            sp: "[{'spName': 'Test'}]",
            // Calls back if errors.
            add: jasmine.createSpyObj('BaseService.add', ['sp']),
            logout: jasmine.createSpy('BaseService.logout'),
            // Calls back if errors.
            fetch: jasmine.createSpyObj('BaseService.fetch', ['selfsp'])
        };

        mockBaseService.add.sp.and.callFake(function(something, cb) {
            cb(); // execute the callback immediately
        });

        mockBaseService.fetch.selfsp.and.callFake(function(something, cb) {
            cb(); // execute the callback immediately
        });

        module('SpPageApp');

        // Let ctrl = MainCtrl and override BaseService in MainCtrl to be
        // the mockBaseService above.
        inject(function($controller) {
            ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
                BaseService: mockBaseService
            });
        });
    });

    it('should have an add function', function() {
        expect(ctrl.add).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

And this is my karma config file's `file` array:

```
files: [
  '../angular.js',
  'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  '../w.js',
  '../sp.js',
  '../s.js',
  '../base.js',
  'tests/test_sp.js',
],
```

Lastly, this is my `sp.js` which has the `SpPageApp` module:

```
angular.module("SpPageApp", ["BaseApp"])
    .controller("MainCtrl", ["$http", "$window", "BaseService", function($http, $window, BaseService) {

        var self = this;

        BaseService.fetch.selfsp(function() {
            self.sp = BaseService.sp;
            self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
        });

        self.add = function() {
            BaseService.add.sp(self.sp, function() {
                self.cerrorMessages = BaseService.cerrorMessages;
            });
        };

        self.logoutUser = function() {
            BaseService.logout();
        };

    }]);
```

The I do `karma start` to test the code, I get an error saying this:

```
Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0) Controller: MainsCtrl should have an add function FAILED
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'and' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/a/Documents/CMS/CMSApp/static/js/karma/tests/test_sp.js:20:45)
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/home/a/Documents/CMS/CMSApp/static/js/karma/tests/test_sp.js:36:20)
Chromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0.006 secChromium 47.0.2526 (Ubuntu 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.034 secs / 0.006 secs)
```

The error says it cannot read the property `add` of defined, and points to this line:

```
expect(ctrl.add).toBeDefined();
```

and that it cannot read the property `and` of undefined, and points to this line:

```
mockBaseService.fetch.selfsp.and.callFake(function(something, cb) {
```

How come Jasmine is saying both `ctrl` and `mockBaseService.fetch.selfsp` are undefined when they are defined in the code?

Edit: For what it's worth, `w.js`, `sp.js` and `s.js` (which karma is loading) all have controllers called `MainCtrl` but each controller is in it's own file and AngularJS module (and in `test_sp.js`, I only load the `SpPageApp` module).

Comment: Why would you call a fake when you've already mocked the service?  Just call the mocked service.

Comment: @DavidL the answer which Phil posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623322/flushing-successful-mock-post-request-using-jasmine-does-not-execute-the-angular calls a fake when  mocking the service, so I decided to use it as well (I'm new to Jasmine so I figured what Phil did was best practice). I believe it is because `ctrl.add()` passes a function to `BaseService.add.sp` which should be called back.

Comment: The alternative to his answer would be something like the following:  mockBaseService = {
            cerrorMessages: 'whatever',
            add: function() { // whatever the add function should do }
        };
In this case, rather than create additional overhead by using a spy object, you simply override the service and inject the overridden mock service into your controller instead, since all you care about testing is the controller, not the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, you can instead mock the service directly and avoid using spies.  In addition, you can tell the $injector to use your mock service instead of the real implementation, allowing you to inject the mock directly when resolving the service, which replaces your normal implementation.

Assuming that your BaseService exists in the SpPageApp module:

```
mockBaseService = {
    cerrorMessages: 'whatever',
    sp: "[{'spName': 'Test'}]",
    add: function (something, cb) { cb() },
    ...
};

module('BaseApp', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('BaseService', mockBaseService);
});

module('SpPageApp');

inject(function($controller) {
    ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', {
    });
});
```

To test it, as mentioned in the comments, you would still want to use a spy to make sure that it was successfully called.

```
it('should have an add function', function() {
    spyOn(mockBaseService, 'add');        
    ctrl.add();
    expect(mockBaseService.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Comment: But mockBaseService needs to have a `mockBaseService.add.sp()` function (see my original post). In the answer you provided, `mockBaseService.add.sp()` does not exist, right? Or am I missing something .. additionally, I wanted to create another test which tests if `ctrl.add()` calls through to `mockBaseService.add.sp()` (i.e. ` expect(mockBaseService.add.sp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl.post, jasmine.any(Function));` .. Is it possible to see if the function was called without using a spy?

Comment: Lastly, `BaseService` exists in the `BaseApp` module which is in `base.js` .. The `BaseApp` module is provided to `SpPageApp` like so: `angular.module("SpPageApp", ["BaseApp"])`. `base.js` is loaded in the karma config file, like so: `files: [ '../base.js', ],`

Comment: You can modify your mock service signature to call whatever you'd like it to call.  As such, you can define add and add.sp.  Nothing prevents you from doing so.  I've updated my answer to match your modules.  In addition, you can still spy on your mock service if you want to.  However, that keeps a cleaner separation of concerns than using mock spy objects inside a mock service.

Comment: Okay thanks. Just for clarification, I wanted to create another test which tests if `ctrl.add()` calls through to `mockBaseService.add.sp()` (i.e. `expect(mockBaseService.add.sp).toHaveBeenCalledWith(ctrl.post, jasmine.any(Function));` .. How can I test if `mockBaseService.add.sp()` was called without using a spy (because that is one of the reasons I initially used a spy).

Comment: I'd be cautious here.  Are you testing your service or your controller?  You're starting to blur the lines and this sounds like service testing, which should be a separate set of tests.  Unless you have access to the output of add.sp(), you can't be certain that it was called without a spy.  And to clarify, there's nothing wrong with spies set up on a test by test basis to verify calls.  My original point was that every single property on every single call does not need to be spied but that rather you can spy on what you need when you need to.

Comment: I just want to verify that the controller actually calls `mockBaseService.add.sp()` when `ctrl.add()` is called. I'm not worried about what `mockBaseService.add.sp()` does at the moment (that testing will be done when testing the service). For now, I'm just testing to see if the controller's `ctrl.add()` call through to `mockBaseService.add.sp()`. I couldn't find any other place to test this functionality so I figured testing it in the controller tests is best. If it's not possible without a spy, wouldn't we need to implement a spy in your original answer?

Comment: Oh right, I get what you mean... I actually did need to spy on all three of the properties (logout, add and fetch) because I wanted to verify that they were being called.

Comment: Correct, but you can customize it per test with the approach I've described, when needed.  I've added an additional example.  Hopefully it clarifies.